# Show/Hide Only One DIV With JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, hover

I have a page of images that I want to show/hide the label of on mouseover.  The images are also links, and the div is called ".smallproj". The JQuery script works great, but of course shows all instances of .smallproj p when I hover over any one instance of .smallproj a.  I know I need to alter the script such that only the instance of .smallproj that's being hovered over shows, but what is the best way to do that in this case?

JQuery script:

```
$(".smallproj a").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(".smallproj p").show();
    },      
    mouseout: function() {
        $(".smallproj p").hide();
    }       
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `this` keyword, which refers to the element that is targeted by the event, and then traverse from it (the `a` element being hovered over) to the `p` element you want to show. The general case, making no assumptions about where they are in relation to one another except that they're both inside something with the `.smallproj` class, would be something like this:

```
$(".smallproj a").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).closest(".smallproj").find("p").show();
    },      
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).closest(".smallproj").find("p").hide();
    }       
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish, and with a great explanation of what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do:

```
$('.smallproj p').hover(function(){
  $(this).show();
});
```

Or, it looks like you also want to hover the link, so try:

```
$('.smallproj a').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('p').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use various ways. Some examples:

**Same Level**

```
$(".smallproj a").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).siblings("p").show();
    },      
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).siblings("p").hide();
    }       
});
```

**Inside the parent**

```
$(".smallproj a").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).parent().find("p").show();
    },      
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).parent().find("p").hide();
    }       
});
```

Information:

1. [Siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
2. [Parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)